# Getting Path from <input type="file"> & Attach to Email

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

Using an `<input type="file" name="fileUpload">` I can get the file path by using Request.MapPath and storing it in a string. But when I do:

`string file = Request.MapPath(Request.Form["fileUpload"]);`
`Attachment.Add(new Attachment(file));`

I get the 'Could not find a part of the path' error. What an I missing in getting the file or attaching the file to the MailMessage object?

Comment: I don't know your app, but usually client (browser) and server (webapp) are on different hosts. You can't access files on other hosts directly. Special upload file control are used for that.

Comment: @Alex R. - If that's so, is there a property I should change on my controller action?

Comment: It's not about the property--it's how you manipulate the files. I'll post a link below for further discussion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you cannot do that because the file has not been written to the server disk; that is, it is buffered in memory. Try this:

```
var destination = Path.GetTempFileName(); // you should probably replace this with a directory the IIS Worker Process has write permission to
try {
Request.Files[0].SaveAs(destination);

Attachment.Add(new Attachment(destination));
// Send attachment
} finally {
File.Delete(destination);
}
```